# iBeacons: Detect walking backwards?

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, beacon, android-ibeacon

I have been researching and reading a number of different articles on what iBeacons and beacon-related apps are capable of doing.However, I couldn't find any answers to a question that came up as I was reading one of those articles.

**Is it possible for a single beacon to send different signals simultaneously so that an app can detect if the person is moving forward or backwards?**

Alternatively, can you guys propose an idea that I could then use to detect if a person is going back or if they are headed the right way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches to this problem, but both have limited reliability:

1. **Full indoor navigation solution**, using beacons as a small building block of a larger system that estimates a user's position as time passes.  Using such a system, you can determine if a user is going the wrong way by knowing their current position and their destination position, and seeing if the estimated distance to the destination gets larger or smaller as time passes.  **Building and using such a system is much more complex than programming an app using beacons**, so while it is worth mentioning, it is really out of scope for a forum like StackOverflow.com.
2. **A simpler solution using two or more beacons, one of which is at the destination.**  The system would determine if the user is walking toward the destination simply by using the distance estimate between the user and the beacon nearest the destination.  If using the Android Beacon Library, ranging updates at approximately 1 Hz, will provide an estimate of the distance in meters to the beacon using `beacon.getDistance()`.  By seeing if this number goes up or down between multiple callbacks, you can determine if the user is getting closer or further away.

There are a number of caveats to both solutions, particularly the second one:

- Beacon distance estimates are based on bluetooth signal strength, so **accuracy is limited by radio noise and multipath**.  It is common for individual estimates to suggest you are getting further away or closer even though you are standing still.
- In order to overcome the noise effects mentioned above, beacon SDKs use multiple samples of signal strength to help smooth out the estimates.  By default the Android Beacon Library (and iOS CoreLocation) use approximately 20 seconds of averaging to help smooth this out.  But **this introduces a lag in the distance estimate**, telling you not where the user is right now, but where the user was *on average* over the last 20 seconds.  On Android, you can adjust this averaging interval to be smaller, but it will increase the error rate of the estimates.

Building your own system that does this therefore means making lots of compromises between time lag, error rate, and time intervals over which a closer/further determination can be determined with sufficient accuracy.  **Whether or not you can make this solution work well enough for your use case really depends on the specifics of what you are trying to accomplish.**  Your best bet may be to experiment with a simple app and see if you can make it work well enough for your use case.